# Insert text in content after 300 words but after closing tag of a Paragraph

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looking for a way to insert an ad or text after *X* amount of words and after the closing tag of the paragraph the last word appears in.

So far, I have only been able to do this after the *X* amount of characters. The problem with this approach is that HTML characters are counted which gives inaccurate results.

```
function chars1($content) {
    // only inject google ads if post is longer than 2500 characters
    $enable_length1 = 2500;
    // insert after the 210th character
    $after_character1 = 2100;

    if (is_single() && strlen($content) > $enable_length1) {
        $before_content1 = substr($content, 0, $after_character1);
        $after_content1 = substr($content, $after_character1);
        $after_content1 = explode('</p>', $after_content1);

        ob_start();
        dynamic_sidebar('single-image-ads-1');
        $text1 = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        array_splice($after_content1, 1, 0, $text1);
        $after_content1 = implode('', $after_content1);

        return $before_content1 . $after_content1;
    } else {
        return $content;
    }
}
//add filter to WordPress with priority 49
add_filter('the_content', 'chars1',49);
```

Another approach I have tried is using:

```
strip_tags($content)
```

and counted the words using:

```
st_word_count()
```

The problem with this is that I have no way of returning the `$content` with the HTML tags

Depending on the size of the post, I will insert up to 5 ad units, with the functions I have above I would need to create a function for each ad. If there is a way to insert all 5 ads using one function that would be great.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deciding what is a word or not can oftentimes be very hard. But if you're alright with an approximate solution, like defining a word as text between two whitespaces, I suggest you implement a simple function yourself.

This may be achieved by iterating over the characters of the string until 150 words are counted and then jumping to the end of the current paragraph. Insert an ad and then repeat until you've added sufficiently many.

Implementing this in your function might look like this

```
function chars1($content) {
    // only inject google ads if post is longer than 2500 characters
    $enable_length1 = 2500;

    // Insert at the end of the paragraph every 300 words
    $after_word1 = 300;

    // Maximum of 5 ads
    $max_ads = 5;

    if (strlen($content) > $enable_length1) {
        $len = strlen($content);
        $i=0;

        // Keep adding untill end of content or $max_ads number of ads has ben inserted
        while($i<$len && $max_ads-->0) {
            // Work our way untill the apropriate length
            $word_cout = 0;
            $in_tag = false;
            while(++$i < $len && $word_cout < $after_word1) {
                if(!$in_tag && ctype_space($content[$i])) {
                    // Whitespace
                    $word_cout++;
                }
                else if(!$in_tag && $content[$i] == '<') {
                    // Begin tag
                    $in_tag = true;
                    $word_cout++;
                }
                else if($in_tag && $content[$i] == '>') {
                    // End tag
                    $in_tag = false;
                }
            }

            // Find the next '</p>'
            $i = strpos($content, "</p>", $i);
            if($i === false) {
                // No more paragraph endings
                break;
            }
            else {
                // Add the length of </p>
                $i += 4;

                // Get ad as string
                ob_start();
                dynamic_sidebar('single-image-ads-1');
                $ad = ob_get_contents();
                ob_end_clean();

                $content = substr($content, 0, $i) . $ad . substr($content, $i);

                // Set the correct i
                $i+= strlen($ad);
            }
        }
    }

    return $content;
}
```

With this approach, it's easy to add new rules.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had to do this myself. This is how I did it. First explode the content on `</p>` tags. Loop over the resulting array, put the end `</p>` back onto the paragraph, do a count on the paragraph with the tags stripped and add it to the global count. Compare the global word count against our word positions. If it's greater, append the content and unset that word position. Stringify and return.

```
function insert_after_words( $content, $words_positions = array(), $content_to_insert = 'Insert Me' ) {

    $total_words_count = 0;

    // Explode content on paragraphs.
    $content_exploded = explode( '</p>', $content );

    foreach ( $content_exploded as $key => $content ) {
        // Put the paragraph tags back.
        $content_exploded[ $key ] .= '</p>';

        $total_words_count += str_word_count( strip_tags( $content_exploded[ $key ] ) );

        // Check the total word count against the word positoning.
        foreach ( $words_positions as $words_key => $words_count ) {
            if ( $total_words_count >= $words_count ) {
                $content_exploded[ $key ] .= PHP_EOL . $content_to_insert;
                unset( $words_positions[ $words_key ] );
            }
        }
    }

    // Stringify content.
    return implode( '', $content_exploded );
}
```