# Show In article ads every x amount of words repeatedly?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a code that shows in-article ads after a specified amount of words, the thing is:
If I write a very long article, the ad will be lost due to text length, so there will be only text showing. What I need to do is to create 1 or 2 ads and make it/them repeat indefinitely every 4 paragraphs and 250 words (just an example), based on article length.

**HERE'S AN EXAMPLE:**

[This blog](https://en.thefunpost.com/40-people-reveal-whats-normal-for-their-country-and-bizarre) has the very same thing that I'm trying to achieve. As you scroll the article, you'll see that more and more ads will be loaded between the article paragraphs.

**THIS IS MY CURRENT CODE:**

```
// Insert ads after a number of words and after the </p> closing tag.
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42801541/insert-text-in-content-after-300-words-but-after-closing-tag-of-a-paragraph

function anunciamentosegundo($content) {
     $ad_code = '<script type="application/javascript">Adsense code goes here</script>';
    
    // only inject google ads if post is longer than 800 characters
    $enable_length1 = 1800;
    // Insert at the end of the paragraph every 200 words
    $after_word1 = 400;
    // Maximum of 2 ads
    $max_ads = 2;
    if (strlen($content) > $enable_length1) {
        $len = strlen($content);
        $i=0;
        // Keep adding untill end of content or $max_ads number of ads has ben inserted
        while($i<$len && $max_ads-->0) {
            // Work our way untill the apropriate length
            $word_cout = 0;
            $in_tag = false;
            while(++$i < $len && $word_cout < $after_word1) {
                if(!$in_tag && ctype_space($content[$i])) {
                    // Whitespace
                    $word_cout++;
                }
                else if(!$in_tag && $content[$i] == '<') {
                    // Begin tag
                    $in_tag = true;
                    $word_cout++;
                }
                else if($in_tag && $content[$i] == '>') {
                    // End tag
                    $in_tag = false;
                }
            }
            // Find the next '</p>'
            $i = strpos($content, "</p>", $i);
            if($i === false) {
                // No more paragraph endings
                break;
            }
            else {
                // Add the length of </p>
                $i += 4;
                // Get ad as string
          ob_start();
          echo $ad_code ; //would normally get printed to the screen/output to browser
          $ad = ob_get_contents();
          ob_end_clean();
                $content = substr($content, 0, $i) . $ad . substr($content, $i);

                // Set the correct i
                $i+= strlen($ad);
            }
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'anunciamentosegundo' );
```

Currently I can show ads after an amount of words and paragraphs, but not every x amount words and paragraphs. What should I do?